# Getting IOPS of the processes on Linux

Tags: linux, iops

So, what value should we read to get the in out operations per second per process?

I've tried /proc/[pid]/io which returns these values:

> root@node:~# cat /proc/31597/io
>   rchar: 213260190
>   wchar: 462308212
>   syscr: 23275044
>   syscw: 47797624
>   read_bytes: 894867968
>   write_bytes: 27645691392
>   cancelled_write_bytes: 0

From definition:

syscr, syscw - Counters for number of I/O operation (respectively: read and write). We may use then to compute average amount of data passed in one system call.

So, I **think** last value of syscw minus the previous value of syscw after a second should give me the write operation count that has been performed by process 31597

However, when the process is doing around 5MB/sec writes (small files), I get the value as 6500 IOPS for writing and that doesn't look correct to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thats the number of read/write syscalls, these dont translate to IOPs, especially when the reads come from page cache and writes go to dirty writeback.

Comment: Any possibility to get the actual IOPS?

Comment: Not unless you write with direct IO (`O_DIRECT`), then you can divide `wchar` by the device sector size. Otherwise it makes little sense to measure IOPS per-process, because all the writes get bundled into writeback or fetched from pagecache. If you *only* care about what really lands on disk you can use `iotop` or `pidstat -d` to obtain pid statistics.

Answer (score 2):

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) can be the program you are looking for.
It is like top, but for I/O.

You need a 2.6.20 or better kernel and root privileges.

Comment: I'm not looking for the byte count. I'm looking for the operation count.